# org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error while accessing enum.values(): class com.mksoft.fbautomate.domain.Account$Type

Tags: java, hibernate, groovy, enums, gradle

This error is driving me nuts!!!

Caused by:  java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.mksoft.fbautomate.domain.Account$Type.values()

The same exact class works fine in a separate Groovy file.

Any ideas/help much appreciated.

Most confusing...

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html

has no values() method!

Here is my class:

```
@Entity class Account {
  @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  public Long id
  enum Type {MYVALUE}
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  public Type type
  public String email
  //  @org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type="encryptedString")
  public String pass
  public String fullName
  String toString() { "type:\""+type+"\",email:\""+email+"\""+",fullName=\""+fullName+"\"" }
}
```

Thank you!
Misha

Answer (score 3):

declare your enum as public

```
public enum Type {MYVALUE}
```

inside your entity

Answer (score 1):

Ok for the record, if I move the enum declaration *outside* the entity it works.

Very very odd...

Misha